# Pyautogui click won't register click on window of application on my desktop

Tags: python, pyautogui

My code will locate the window with a picture and then move the mouse to the correct position but the click doesn't actually register on that window. The window does register when I click on it manually (like normal).

```py
img = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(img location) 

pyautogui.moveTo(img) 

pyautogui.click()
```

Comment: Is the argument of `locateCenterOnScreen()` a pasting mistake?

Comment: try `pyautogui.click(button = "left", duration = 0.1)`

Comment: I tried 'pyautogui.click(button = "left", duration = 0.01)' , it hovers over the are it need to click but its like its like the click is happening inside pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

Some applications, like certain video games, have protection against this kind of stuff. The solution is to build an exe and run is as admin. Try that. This tutorial worked for me:
https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-easily-convert-a-python-script-to-an-executable-file-exe-4966e253c7e9